# coredata subquery with multiple conditions / relations

Tags: core-data, subquery, nspredicate

I have the following model:

[image]

how can I get all the PT objects where groupId == '2'?

I have tried several ways, but without success.

With this query, I get one result only:

```
            NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
            request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Status" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
            request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"group.groupId == %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSArray *resultSet = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
            [request release];

            NSLog(@"array count: %lu", (unsigned long)[resultSet count]);

            NSPredicate *thePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hasBeenDeleted == %@ AND (ANY hasStatus IN %@)",
                                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],
                                         [NSSet setWithArray:resultSet]];

            [self.ptListViewController refreshDataWithPredicate:thePredicate];
```

Answer (score 2):

You could start with a template "GROUP_BY_GROUP_ID" and add it to the managedObjectModel ...

```
    - (NSManagedObjectModel *)managedObjectModel {
        // The managed object model for the application. It is a fatal error for the application not to be able to find and load its model.
        if (_managedObjectModel != nil) {
            return _managedObjectModel;
        }
        NSURL *modelURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"GroupdId2" withExtension:@"momd"];
        _managedObjectModel = [[NSManagedObjectModel alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:modelURL];


        NSFetchRequest *tmpTemplate;
        NSEntityDescription *tmpEntity;
        NSPredicate *tmpPredicate;

        // 1. GROUP_BY_GROUP_ID
        tmpEntity = [[_managedObjectModel entitiesByName] objectForKey:@"Group"];
        tmpTemplate = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
        [tmpTemplate setEntity:tmpEntity];
        tmpPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"(groupId == $value)"];
        [tmpTemplate setPredicate:tmpPredicate];
        [_managedObjectModel setFetchRequestTemplate:tmpTemplate forName:@"GROUP_BY_GROUP_ID"];

        return _managedObjectModel;
    }
```

Here is the appropriate fetch method:

```
    - (NSArray *)fetchGroupByGroupId:(NSNumber *)value
    {
        NSError *error = nil;

        NSManagedObjectModel *model = _managedObjectModel;

        NSDictionary *substitutionDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:value, @"value", nil];

        NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [model fetchRequestFromTemplateWithName:@"GROUP_BY_GROUP_ID" substitutionVariables:substitutionDictionary];

        NSArray *results = [_managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

        return results;
    }
```

Now you can start fetching PT entities like this (Xcode lets you generate the NSManagedObject subclasses for all entities):

```
    NSArray *groups=[self fetchGroupByGroupId:@(2)];
    NSMutableSet *resultPT=[[NSMutableSet alloc] init];
    for (Group *group in groups) {
        for (Status *status in group.hasStatus) {
            for (PTStatus *ptstatus in status.ptStatus) {
                if (ptstatus.targetPT!=nil) {
                    [resultPT addObject:ptstatus.targetPT];
                }
                if (ptstatus.pt!=nil) {
                    [resultPT addObject:ptstatus.pt];
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

In `resultPT` now you will find all different PT entities "with" groupId == '2'.

You find a XCode 6.1 project here: [XCode 6.1 project on Dropbox](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/9q1496sxwdvd9hi/AADq2vpe_-0bOTAZBT4YJ2ada?dl=0).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Markus, thanks for your example. The way I was doing exampled above, I was getting 1 object has return. What was I doing wrong with those lines? Something is missing. I think they are cleaner, although your solution seams to work.

Comment: Rui, two points ... 1.) your code above shows a fetch of "Status" objects. According to your model and if i am not totally wrong there is no "hasBeenDeleted" and no "hasStatus" attributes in "resultSet"-Array ("Status") objects and "NSPredicate *thePredicate ..." cannot not work as expected 2.) Apple recommends in the FAQ of http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData: Q:"I have a to-many relationship from Entity A to Entity B. How do I fetch [...] Entity B?" A: "You don’t. [...] invoke the appropriate key-value [...] accessor method on [...] Entity A".

Comment: Markus, the Fetch Entity is "PT". the predicate you see takes a list of PTs and see what of those are in a NSSet os Status. What I don't understand is why ir only returns one PT. I think something is wrong in the *resultSet from Status fetch.

Answer (score 0):

I found it!
I had a bug when relating the Status with the Group.
Correct code for achieving:

```
            NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
            request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PTStatus" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
            request.predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY status.group.groupId == %@", [NSNumber numberWithInt:2]];
            NSError *error = nil;
            NSArray *resultSet = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
            [request release];

            NSLog(@"array count: %lu", (unsigned long)[resultSet count]);

            NSPredicate *thePredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"hasBeenDeleted == %@ AND (ANY hasStatus IN %@)",
                                         [NSNumber numberWithBool:NO],
                                         [NSSet setWithArray:resultSet]];

            [self.ptListViewController refreshDataWithPredicate:thePredicate];
```

and `[self.ptListViewController refreshDataWithPredicate:thePredicate];` has

```
- (void)refreshDataWithPredicate:(NSPredicate *)predicate{
    self.fetchedResultsController = nil;
    [NSFetchedResultsController deleteCacheWithName:@"PTs_Cache"];

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    request.entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"PT" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];

    request.sortDescriptors = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                               [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"requestDate" ascending:NO],
                               [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"number" ascending:YES],
                               nil];

    request.predicate = predicate;

    request.fetchBatchSize = 40;

    NSString *sectionNameKeyPathString = @"dateSection_transient";
    NSFetchedResultsController *frc = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:request
                                                                          managedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext
                                                                            sectionNameKeyPath:sectionNameKeyPathString
                                                                                     cacheName:@"PTs_Cache"];
    [request release];

    self.fetchedResultsController = frc;
    [frc release];

    [self.theTable reloadData];
}
```

Comment: It's easy to save the second predicate if you take `[NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"((ANY hasStatus.status.group.groupId == $groupdid) AND (ANY hasStatus.hasBeenDeleted == $deleted))"]` in the database request. So will get the PT objects directly. Building sections and sorting can be done in this request accordingly. [XCode 6.1 Objc Sample](https://github.com/augustjohann/GroupId2.git).